# Why is my SD card not transferring files to SSD?

Tags: 12.04, sd-card

I have a memory card reader, and when I insert a sd card and began to copy pictures or vidioes from the sd card to my ssd(hard disk) after one or two files the error appears:

`Error splicing file: Input/output error`

and the sd card disappeared from the computer and I need to restart the computer to see here again ,and the all things again and again until I finish

Comment: Then the card is defective.  Check `dmesg` or /var/log/syslog for more detailed error messages.

Comment: It's also possible that the card reader is defective.

Answer (score 0):

troylatroy is likely correct. It could also be your card reader is failing. It's possible that not all the files are lost. Use ddrescue from the terminal to attempt recovery. Use a log file so that ddrescue can work as intended.
The manual can be found here: https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html

Example 9 in the manual specifically mentions your problem..

I have successfully used ddrescue many times to recover data from failing storage devices.